# How can I make an equal distance between the years of the x-axis on a df.plot()?

Tags: pandas, plot, time-series, linegraph

I want to make an equal distance between the years of the x-axis, however currently the distribution between 2007 and 2014 is very small and between 2014 and 2015 really big. How can I make the distribution equally? Thanks for your help!

My code is: `reviews_english_date.plot(x="Datum Review Gast Jahr",y="Review Gast Count")`

[Picture of Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evmw6.png)

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv347.png)

Comment: Can you share your dataframe (or a subset of it)?

Comment: @tomjn Of course - i added it :)